# How to close dashboard programmatically using AppleScript?

Tags: javascript, applescript

I'm developing a small dashboard widget that allows user to open a system preference pane.

Opening the preference pane is no problem (but looks awful :p)

```
widget.system('osascript ' +
              '-e \'tell app "system preferences" to activate\'' +
              '-e \'<snip…> open correct pane\'')
```

The problem is that even if the preference pane opens, Dashboard stays open too.

I have found ways of opening it:

```
tell app "Dashboard" to launch
```

but no way to **close** it, `close` raises an exception and `quit` does nothing :/

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Dashboard" to launch
delay 3
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

or maybe a keystroke...

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 53
```

Comment: Nop, doesn't work :/ Finder goes to the foreground, but dashboard stays here

Comment: Second solution works if you know precisely which key to press. Here it's key code 111 (F12) for instance. Not a good solution IMHO but it seems it's the best we've got :/

Answer (score 0):

While sending key code 111 works for me, as it toggles Dashboard on and off, it doesn't really allow you to control the state. Sometimes you want to be able to turn Dashboard off, but if it's already off, you don't want to turn it back on (which key code 111 will do).

Instead, use key code 27, or ESCAPE:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 27
```

That will close dashboard if it's open, but should not do anything if it's already closed.

I use this technique periodically on a Mac we have connected to a TV, so that it will refresh the dashboard widgets by closing dashboard and reopening it.

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 27
delay 3
tell application "Dashboard" to launch
```